# How to codeCoverageIgnore for specific test suite only in phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have defined two test-suites in `phpunit.xml` file, one for Unit Tests and other for Functional Test. For some functions which can't be unit tested, I am using `@codeCoverageIgnore` in my source code. But I do not want this code to be ignored when running Functional Tests.

Is it possible to add test-suite name to `codeCoverageIgnore` so that my code is ignored for unit tests and not for functional tests.

Comment: What if you used multiple .xml config files, and use the --configuration flag to toggle which one you want to use?  Would that help?  i.e., `function.xml` and `unit.xml` or something like that ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. If you think it should be possible then [please open a ticket](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/php-code-coverage/issues/new).

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen The "No, that is not possible." is the answer.